# ArchUnit to test actual layered architecture

Tags: junit5, archunit

Currently in our project we have layered architecture implemented in following way where Controller, Service, Repository are placed in the same package for each feature, for instance:

- feature1:

  - Feature1Controller
  - Feature1Service
  - Feature1Repository
- feature2:

  - Feature2Controller
  - Feature2Service
  - Feature2Repository

I've found following example of arch unit test where such classes are placed in dedicated packages https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit-Examples/blob/master/example-junit5/src/test/java/com/tngtech/archunit/exampletest/junit5/LayeredArchitectureTest.java

Please suggest whether there is possibility to test layered architecture when all layers are in single package

Answer (score 2):

If the file name conventions are followed properly across your project, how about you write custom test cases instead of using `layeredArchitecture()`.

For Example:

```
classes().that().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Service")
    .should().onlyBeAccessed().byClassesThat().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Controller")

noClasses().that().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Service")
    .should().accessClassesThat().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Controller")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old. But for the record, this has been possible for a while using predicates for the layers, e.g.

```
layeredArchitecture().consideringAllDependencies()

  .layer("Controllers").definedBy(HasName.Predicates.nameEndingWith("Controller"))
  .layer("Services").definedBy(HasName.Predicates.nameEndingWith("Service"))
  .layer("Repository").definedBy(HasName.Predicates.nameEndingWith("Repository"))

  .whereLayer("Controllers").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer()
  .whereLayer("Services").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Controllers")
  .whereLayer("Repository").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Services")
```

However, I'm not sure how well this works in practice. Because usually you don't just have classes following this naming pattern and that's it. A service might also have some POJO as method parameter type (e.g. `MyInput`) and that should maybe for example not be used by repositories as well. Also, using forward dependency rules (`mayOnlyAccessLayers(..)`) this might then cause unwanted violations.